# Nanny Tax Withholding threshold

Tags: united-states, withholding

We hired a part time nanny in May. We expected to exceed the $1900 threshold and started deducting FICA taxes. Now at the end of the year, we've payed her less than $1600. Must I still file a w-2 for her, or can I just refund her the money?